# User Vs. Connected App

Tags: integration, user, connected-apps

I'm a little confused. I need to integrate an external platform with Salesforce to consume REST services. What is the difference between using an integration user with API permission rather than creating a connected app? In both cases a user must be created on Salesforce. Example scenarios are welcome. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Connected apps give you power to add authorization to your user authentication flow .

Using authorization , you can be specific when defining the privileges for your authenticating user.

You can use various oauth 2.0 flow(like user agent, web server or JWT ) to authenticate without storing the passwords to securely authenticate .

The other benefit is using connected apps you can revoke the permissions any time easily .

Also using a common API user is not always requirement and one may need login per user and connected apps provider per user oauth.

Comment: Just a bit of extra commentary. The "not needing to store the password" bit is _really_ important. Using a connected app also allows you to easily revoke privileges.

Answer (score 2):

A Connected App is simply a matter of authentication, the other primary modes being JWT, SAML, and SOAP authentication (Connected Apps are typically Oauth2). You would not contrast this to an Integration User, which is simply a user typically created to synchronize data between Salesforce and one or more external systems (possibly other Salesforce orgs).

The real question is "integration user" versus "per-user access." With an integration user, there is no fine-grained control for multiple users. This is typically okay with an external system, since the goal is to synchronize all the available data that meets whatever criteria is necessary. Per-user access would be when you want to provide external users direct access to Salesforce data in real-time and need better security controls.

You can connect an Integration User via a Connected App, JWT, SOAP, SAML, etc. The method of obtaining a session ID or access token (they are mostly synonymous as far as Salesforce is concerned) is irrelevant. Feel free to use whichever authentication method is supported by your technology stack. As long as your goal is just synchronization of data, an Integration User is an ideal solution. If you need better security controls, then creating users for each user accessing the data is preferred (and technically, required by the Salesforce Master Service Agreement).

Comment: I worry this answer is misleading. It seems like the better integration strategy is a connected app which allows for more access control, quickly revoking of privileges, and not exposing login information to other services. It seems like the default should be to use a connected app. I'm not even sure why you'd ever want to use username/pass for access, that seems like encouraging bad security practices

Comment: @AndyRay I think you misunderstood the same concepts as the OP. A Connected App is just one of several ways to connect to a Salesforce session. SAML and JWT also don't expose the username or password (in fact, with SAML, the user may not even *have* a Salesforce password!), and none of these methods except SOAP offer any possibility of handling the user's password (and you can use SOAP without a password in some circumstances, too). Privileges are controlled by a user profile/permset, not a Connected App (try turning off just Accounts via Connected Apps).

Comment: @AndyRay Well, okay, technically you can use username/password with a Connected App, too, which is discouraged for anything other than a quicker development cycle when you're testing an app. A Connected App isn't one specific authentication mode, and while it does offer scopes, scopes only allow access to entire APIs, not specific sub-functions within a given API. The original question asks to compare "Integration User" to "Connected App", which is like comparing apples to space shuttles. There's simply no relationship at all.

Comment: Is there a way to authenticate a user using a JWT flow without a connected app?

Comment: @AndyRay I don't know enough about JWT to know for sure. The current documentation seems to imply that a Connected App is required, but I'm pretty sure that I've seen JWT without Connected Apps in the past (maybe the functionality was rolled in to Connected Apps at some point?). Still, my answer is more about how Connected Apps are just one possible method of integration. I also could have mentioned Canvas Apps, etc.

Comment: Then I stand by my comment. When choosing an integration strategy, connecting as a user with user/pass *should* be compared to connecting through a connected app

Comment: @AndyRay Again, the choice of connection has nothing to do with the user's permissions. You can still use SAML, which definitely does not use a Connected App, or you can use a Session ID from a Workflow Outbound Message, or a Canvas App.